# I can rest easy knowing that she’s safely home. (easy is a complement or an adverb?)

Tags: parts-of-speech

> I can rest easy knowing that she’s safely home.

What's the part of speech of 'easy' in the sentence above?

Comment: It's an adverb formed by conversion from the adjective form "easy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It functions as an adverb - although note that *easy* is usually an adjective, and using *easy* as an adverb is pretty much limited to a few phrases such as *rest easy*, *take it easy*, etc., or in the sense of "careful" (*Easy with that glass, it's fragile*).